# mLab connect via standard MongoDb URI fails but succeeds via MongoShell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab

I'm currently running my web page locally and im trying to connect it to a mongo server hosted on mlab.

I can connect to my db via mongoshell, but when i try via URI it'll fail using the exact same credentials.

```
mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds131782.mlab.com:31782/gialongdb
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "trying via URI"? Are you connecting using the node driver? If so, which version of the node driver are you using, and what error message is displayed when the connection fails?

Comment: @AdamHarrison yes im using node driver. Im using vers 1.3.10

`MongoError: auth failed`

Answer (score 0):

The 1.3.10 version of the node driver doesn't support the authentication mechanism used in the [more recent versions of MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/#upgrade-drivers). Using an older version that is compatible with this auth mechanism will yield the 'auth failed' message.

Try updating your driver to a newer version (post 1.4.29). The newest release is [2.2.29](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/releases).